# Number of guesses binary search would take to reach number

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, binary

Essentially, given a start of an inclusive integer range $s$, an end of the range $f$ such that $s \le f$, and an integer $n$ such that $s \le n \le f$, how many guesses would binary search take to find $n$?

For example, let $s = 1$, $f = 20$, and $n = 9$. Then, binary search would take $5$ guesses as follows: 10, 5, 7, 8, 9.

For another example, let $s = 1$, $f = 20$, and $n = 10$. Then, binary search would take $1$ guess as follows: $10$.

Can this be generalized to a formula with these 3 inputs?

Here is some pseudocode for reference that calculates the number of guesses for a specific combination with $g$ being the current number of guesses and $m$ being the current guess:

```
binary_search(s, f, n)
    g = 0
    
    while s <= f
        g = g + 1
        m = int((s + f) / 2)
        
        if m == n
            return g
        else if m < n
            s = m + 1
        else
            f = m - 1
```

**Edit:**

Using the information provided by [ronno](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32766/ronno), here is the recurrence that we would have to solve to find the closed-form expression after performing the transformations $(s, f, n) \mapsto (0, f - s, n - s)$:

Note: Removed $s$ below as $s = 0$ after the above transformations.
$$
\text{binary_search}(f, n) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } m = n \\
1 + \text{binary_search}(f - m - 1, n - m - 1) &\text{if } m < n \\
1 + \text{binary_search}(m - 1, n) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\ \text{where } m = \left \lfloor \frac{f}{2} \right \rfloor
$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145553/discussion-on-question-by-gigi-bayte-2-number-of-guesses-binary-search-would-tak); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.